# Automatically append text in cell to URL in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google, formatting

Suppose I have a Google spreadsheet with a column of codes which correspond to a URL suffix. In this case, I have papers on arXiv listed as follows:

| arXiv |
| --- |
| 1712.03255 |
| 2303.14090 |
| 2012.02922 |

How would I format these cells, such that the text in each cell remains the same, but each is a hyperlink to the URLs like so:

| arXiv |
| --- |
| https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03255 |
| https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.14090 |
| https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.02922 |

Answer (score 1):

You can't format a cell as a hyperlink, you must either edit the cell or use a formula in another cell to create the hyperlink.

#### Automatic Hyperlink

Sheets automatically converts most valid URL formats in cells without the need to use any function.

- **Example 1:**   `="https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.03255"`
- **Example 2:**   `="https://arxiv.org/abs/"&B2`    //   `B2`=`"1712.03255"`
- **Example 3:**   `=B1&B2`     //   `B1:"https://arxiv.org/abs/"` ;   `B2:"1712.03255"`

```
# Array Formula
=ARRAYFORMULA(B1&A2:A4)

# Single Cell Formula
=$B$1&A2
```

[image]

#### Hyperlink Function

The [HYPERLINK](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313) function `HYPERLINK(url, [link_label])`can be used if you want the `link_label` to be different than the `url`.

```
# Array Formula
=ARRAYFORMULA(HYPERLINK(B1&A2:A4,A2:A4))

# Single Cell Formula
=HYPERLINK($B$1&A2,A2)
```

[image]